# Is there a recent way to write the env variable in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the dataFrame 'pr' and clear the environment 'env' from unused variables

```
evalq({pr <- pr.OHLCV(Data, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume)
    rm(list = c("Data", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"))
    }, 
 env)
```

> Error in evalq({ : object 'env' not found

Comment: per the error message, the object `env` doesn't exist. What argument of `evalq()` are you trying to pass `env` to, and what is your intention with that argument?

Comment: I joined vectors received from a time series terminal into a data frame by changing the format of start time bar to a POSIXct  ,then the code above is to calculate the data frame and clear the environment from unused variables

Comment: from which environment are you trying to remove the variables?

Comment: Can I refer you to the site I read about the code snippet and how to process the data in R?: https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/3486

Comment: It appears the writer created their own environment rather than using the default `globalenv()`. Because you have not created `env` your function cannot find it. You can read more about environments [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html). Try removing the env argument.